# How to turn on Youtube Subtitles in AppleTV?

Tags: video, appletv, subtitle

The youtube video is subtitled, how can I turn it on on my Apple TV?

I tried configuring languages and closed caption, but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple TV doesn't support YouTube closed captioning.
The closed captioning you've enabled is where video files have subtitles.
The same functionality was missing on the pre-iOS 6 YouTube app, so I'm not surprised that it doesn't exist on the Apple TV.

If you want to submit feedback to Apple about this, you can do so [here](http://www.apple.com/feedback/appletv.html).